# excel/VBA how to assign the variable length of an array to integer variable

Tags: arrays, excel, variant, vba

In excel/VBA I have this code

```
Dim colName as Variant
Dim lengthToDispl as Integer
colName = Array("A", "B", "C")
lengthToDispl = colName.length
```

I get the following error 'Object Required'. It relates to the last line.

How do I assign the length of an array of variable length (containing strings) to a variable (integer)?

Comment: `lengthToDispl = ubound(colName)` should do it.

Comment: fwiw, the length of the first string in the array is `Len(colName(0))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you want to return the 'size' of the array is the [UBound function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx) which returns the **Upper Boundary**. This is often used with its counterpart, the [LBound function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a7w1ac(v=vs.90).aspx) which returns the **Lower Boundary**.

This may or may not be returning the number you are looking for. Some arrays are arranged with a zero-based index and some have a one-based index. It depends on the way that they are declared and assigned.

```
colName = Array("A", "B", "C")
```

The above creates an array with a zero-based index and three elements in position `colName(0)`, `colName(1)` and `colName(2)`. The UBound (e.g. `UBound(colName)`) will return 2, not 3. To cycle through it, use both LBound and UBound.

```
for i = LBound(colName) to UBound(colName)
    debug.print colName(i)
next i
```

When assigning values from a worksheet's cells, you get a one-based, two dimensioned array, even if you are only collecting the values from a single column or row. The other dimension or **Rank** is simply **1 to 1**.

```
colName = Range("A1:C2").Value2
```

This creates a two-dimensioned array with a one-based index as in `ReDim colName (1 to 2, 1 to 3)`.

```
debug.print LBound(colName, 1) & " to " & UBound(colName, 1)
debug.print LBound(colName, 2) & " to " & UBound(colName, 2)

for i = LBound(colName, 1) to UBound(colName, 1)
    for j = LBound(colName, 2) to UBound(colName, 2)
        debug.print colName(i, j)
    next j
next i
```

I recommend using both [LBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a7w1ac(v=vs.90).aspx) and [UBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx) when dealing with the elements of an array.